# Why do i have "OutOfMemoryError" in my Kmeans CuPy code?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, k-means, cupy

im really new for gpu coding i found this Kmeans cupy code my propouse is work with a large data base (n,3) for example to realize about the timing difference on gpu and cpu , i wanna have a huge number of clusters but i am getting a memory management error. Can someone give me the route I should take to research and fix it, i already research but i have not a clear start yet.

```py
import contextlib
import time

import cupy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

@contextlib.contextmanager
def timer(message):
    cupy.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
    start = time.time()
    yield
    cupy.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
    end = time.time()
    print('%s:  %f sec' % (message, end - start))

    
var_kernel = cupy.ElementwiseKernel(
    'T x0, T x1, T c0, T c1', 'T out',
    'out = (x0 - c0) * (x0 - c0) + (x1 - c1) * (x1 - c1)',
    'var_kernel'
)
sum_kernel = cupy.ReductionKernel(
    'T x, S mask', 'T out',
    'mask ? x : 0',
    'a + b', 'out = a', '0',
    'sum_kernel'
)
count_kernel = cupy.ReductionKernel(
    'T mask', 'float32 out',
    'mask ? 1.0 : 0.0',
    'a + b', 'out = a', '0.0',
    'count_kernel'
)
    
    
def fit_xp(X, n_clusters, max_iter):
    assert X.ndim == 2
 
    # Get NumPy or CuPy module from the supplied array.
    xp = cupy.get_array_module(X)

    n_samples = len(X)
    
    # Make an array to store the labels indicating which cluster each sample is
    # contained.
    pred = xp.zeros(n_samples)
    
    # Choose the initial centroid for each cluster.
    initial_indexes = xp.random.choice(n_samples, n_clusters, replace=False)
    centers = X[initial_indexes]
    
    for _ in range(max_iter):
        # Compute the new label for each sample.
        distances = xp.linalg.norm(X[:, None, :] - centers[None, :, :], axis=2)
        new_pred = xp.argmin(distances, axis=1)
    
        # If the label is not changed for each sample, we suppose the
        # algorithm has converged and exit from the loop.
        if xp.all(new_pred == pred):
            break
        pred = new_pred
    
        # Compute the new centroid for each cluster.
        i = xp.arange(n_clusters)
        mask = pred == i[:, None]
        sums = xp.where(mask[:, :, None], X, 0).sum(axis=1)
        counts = xp.count_nonzero(mask, axis=1).reshape((n_clusters, 1))
        centers = sums / counts
    
    return centers, pred
    
    
def fit_custom(X, n_clusters, max_iter):
    assert X.ndim == 2
    
    n_samples = len(X)
    
    pred = cupy.zeros(n_samples,dtype='float32')
    
    initial_indexes = cupy.random.choice(n_samples, n_clusters, replace=False)
    centers = X[initial_indexes]
    
    for _ in range(max_iter):
        distances = var_kernel(X[:, None, 0], X[:, None, 1],
                                   centers[None, :, 1], centers[None, :, 0])
        new_pred = cupy.argmin(distances, axis=1)
        if cupy.all(new_pred == pred):
            break
        pred = new_pred
    
        i = cupy.arange(n_clusters)
        mask = pred == i[:, None]
        sums = sum_kernel(X, mask[:, :, None], axis=1)
        counts = count_kernel(mask, axis=1).reshape((n_clusters, 1))
        centers = sums / counts
    
    return centers, pred
    
    
def draw(X, n_clusters, centers, pred, output):
    # Plot the samples and centroids of the fitted clusters into an image file.
    for i in range(n_clusters):
        labels = X[pred == i]
        plt.scatter(labels[:, 0], labels[:, 1], c=numpy.random.rand(3))
    plt.scatter(
        centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], s=120, marker='s', facecolors='y',
        edgecolors='k')
    plt.savefig(output)
  
    
def run_cpu(gpuid, n_clusters, num, max_iter, use_custom_kernel):##, output
    samples = numpy.random.randn(num, 3)
    X_train = numpy.r_[samples + 1, samples - 1]
    
    with timer(' CPU '):
        centers, pred = fit_xp(X_train, n_clusters, max_iter)
    
    
    
def run_gpu(gpuid, n_clusters, num, max_iter, use_custom_kernel):##, output
    samples = numpy.random.randn(num, 3)
    X_train = numpy.r_[samples + 1, samples - 1]
    
    with cupy.cuda.Device(gpuid):
        X_train = cupy.asarray(X_train)
    
        with timer(' GPU '):
            if use_custom_kernel:
                centers, pred = fit_custom(X_train, n_clusters, max_iter)
            else:
                centers, pred = fit_xp(X_train, n_clusters, max_iter)
```

btw i am working in colab pro 25GB(RAM), the code is working with n_clusters=200 and num= 1000000 but if i use bigger numbers the error appear, i am running the code like this:

```py
run_gpu(0,200,1000000,10,True)
```

[This is the error that i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT7Ss.png)

Any suggestion will be welcome, thanks for your time.

Comment: 25GB RAM don't do much for you when your GPU only has 2GB global memory. So what GPU are you using?

Comment: Gen RAM Free: 26.3 GB  | Proc size: 185.6 MB
GPU RAM Free: 16280MB | Used: 0MB | Util   0% | Total 16280MB

Comment: Can you pinpoint (via single-stepping or adding print statements) where exactly the error appears? Especially if it appears before or in the loop going till `max_iter`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late replay, i put a link at the end with and image of my error, as you say is inside the loop on the "var_kernel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that CuPy is clever enough not to create explicit copies of the broadcasted input of `var_kernel`, the output `distances` has to have a size of `2 * num * num_clusters` which are exactly the 6,400,000,000 Bytes it is trying to allocate. You could have a way smaller memory footprint by never actually writing the distances to memory which means fusing the `var_kernel` with `argmin`. See [this](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/user_guide/kernel.html#kernel-fusion) part of the docs.

If I understand the example there correctly, this should work:

```py
@cupy.fuse(kernel_name='argmin_distance')
def argmin_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return cupy.argmin((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2), axis = 1)
```

The next question would be where the other 13.7GB come from. A big part of them might just be the instances of `distances` from earlier iterations. I'm not a CuPy expert, but at least in Python/Numpy your use of distances inside the loop would not reuse the same memory, but allocate more memory each time you call the `var_kernel`. The same problem is visible with `pred` which is allocated before the loop. If CuPy does things the Numpy way, the solution would be to just put `[:]` in there like

```py
pred[:] = new_pred
```

or

```py
distances[:,:,:] = var_kernel(X[:, None, 0], X[:, None, 1],
                              centers[None, :, 1], centers[None, :, 0])
```

For this to work, you need to allocate `distances` before the loop as well. Also this isn't needed anymore when using kernel fusion, so just take it as an example. It may be best to allocate everything beforehand and then use this syntax everywhere in the loop.

I don't know enough about CuPy to answer why `fit_xp` doesn't have the same problem (or does it?). But my guess would be that garbage collection with CuPy objects works differently there. If garbage collection were "quick enough" in `fit_custom` it should work even without kernel fusion or reusing already allocated arrays.

Other problems or at least oddities with your code:

- Why are you comparing the zeroth coordinate of `centers` with the first coordinate of `X`? Wouldn't it make more sense to call

```py
distances = var_kernel(X[:, None, 0], X[:, None, 1],
                       centers[None, :, 0], centers[None, :, 1])
```

- Why are you creating 3D data when only using the projection on the 2D plane? So why not

```py
samples = numpy.random.randn(num, 2)
```

- Why are you using floats for (the initial version of) `pred`? The `argmin` should give an integer type result.